# Необходимо ли синхронизировать методы классов, которые не имеют состояния?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Необходимо ли синхронизировать методы классов, которые не имеют состояния? Например, у меня есть класс:

```
@Slf4j
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeServiceService {

    @Setter
    private SomeDao someDao;

    @Override
    public void doSomething(Event event) {
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        val date = new Date();
        event.put("someDate", date);

        val someId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        event.put("someId", someId);
        ...
        someDao.save(event);
    }
}
```

Если выполнить этот код в нескольких потоках, каждый поток создаст свою копию локальных переменных? Этот метод будет вызываться из множества потоков, например. И я не уверен, что без синхронизации можно обойтись здесь. Но и не уверен, что она нужна. Например, что будет в случае @Utils-классов, нужно ли синхронизировать их методы? DAO здесь - это Spring синглтон.

Comment: Методы по идее в принципе не имют состояния, состояние - это к структурам данных, типа классов. А конкретно в вашем примере, метод использует состояние класса (`someDao.save(event);`) и даже получается имеет побочные эффекты (что то куда то сохранится) - в таких случаях нет однозначеного ответа, надо синхронизировать или не надо. Если это просто доступ БД, то обычно не надо, но могут быть ньюансы.

Comment: в вот если метод не использует никакое состояние и не имеет побочных эффектов, то скорее всего его не надо синхронизировать, как пример просто сложение 2 чисел типа `int add(int a, int b) { return a + b;}`

Comment: Спасибо, т.е. если у меня есть, например, какой-то утилитарный класс, в котором я тупо из Deque делаю массив байтов и у класса нет никакого состояния... то мне не нужно синхронизировать его методы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Локальные переменные пересекаться не будут -- у каждого потока свой стек. Вопрос только к полю someDao -- надо ли синхронизировать зависит от реализации.

Comment: Спасибо, к локальным переменным как раз был вопрос.